# Using a bijective function, prove there are equally many subsets of size $k$ as $n-k$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S$ be a set with cardinality $n > 0$. Prove using a bijective function that the number of subsets of $S$ of size $k$ is equal to the number of subsets of $S$ of size $n−k$.

Comment: Think: $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $k=1$, then $\{1\} \leftrightarrow \{2,3,4\}$....

Comment: If I want to choose five things on my list that I want to do I can pick the things that I *like*...  or... pick the things I don't like.

Comment: I don't understand how to approach this proof. Should I be proving bijection first through proving surjectivity and injectivity or prove the equality first which then implies the bijectivity?

Comment: You should first create a function, then prove its bijectivity. See the hint I have given in the previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $A\subset S$, $\#A=k$, define $f(A)=S\setminus A$.

This is a well-defined function, $f(A)$ is a set of size $\#S-\#A=n-k$, if $A_1\neq A_2$ ($k$-element subsets of $S$) then $f(A_1)\neq f(A_2)$.